# issue while installing Node-Red on mac Node.js v 8.1.2 Node-Red v0.16.2

Tags: node.js, node-red

```
Welcome to Node-RED
===================

19 Jun 07:20:59 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.16.2
19 Jun 07:20:59 - [info] Node.js  version: v8.1.2
19 Jun 07:20:59 - [info] Darwin 16.6.0 x64 LE
19 Jun 07:21:00 - [info] Loading palette nodes
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/abdulkurdi/.node-red/.config.json'
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/myname/.node-red/.config.json' }
19 Jun 07:21:09 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
```

when I check the link localhost:1880 or the http://127.0.0.1:1880/ it says not started

thanks

Comment: this is from the terminal on mac

Comment: sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
/usr/local/bin/node-red -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js
/usr/local/bin/node-red-pi -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/bin/node-red-pi
+ node-red@0.16.2
updated 3 packages in 15.834s

Comment: worked by running the command sudo node-red